# How can I chmod a binary file while using adb

Tags: android, linux, shell, filesystems, adb

```
root@android:/sdcard/docker/docker-latest/usr/local/bin # ll
ll
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw 14614452 2015-01-24 15:27 docker
root@android:/sdcard/docker/docker-latest/usr/local/bin # chmod 777 docker
chmod 777 docker
root@android:/sdcard/docker/docker-latest/usr/local/bin # ll
ll
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw 14614452 2015-01-24 15:27 docker
root@android:/sdcard/docker/docker-latest/usr/local/bin #
```

this is how I try to chmod a file,but it doesn't work.
I've seen a similar question in SO,the answer says I should remount the sdcard ,but I'm not sure How to use the command,Can somebody tell me the exact command to remount sdcard? the file I need to mount is the 'sdcard',then,what's the mountpoint?
Or are there any other solutions?
Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic because it belongs on [Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Cactus thank you for leting me know that,I'm new here.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **fdisk -l** [[1]] to identify the device, and then **umount and mount** [[2]] to remount it.

[1] : http://www.computerhope.com/unix/fdisk.htm

[2] : https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/mount-unmount.html